# $\sum_{i_1,...,i_k}A_{i_1}\cdots A_{i_k}=\sum_{i_1}\textrm{stuff}+\cdots+\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_k}\textrm{stuff}$, where $A_i$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Suppose we have a set of noncommuting matrices $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$. I want to rewrite the sum over all possible combinations of $k$ these (with replacement), i.e. the sum has $n^k$ terms. I want to rewrite it as
$$\sum_{i_1,...,i_k}A_{i_1}\cdots A_{i_k}=\sum_{i_1}\textrm{stuff}+\sum_{i_1<i_2}\textrm{stuff}+\cdots+\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_k}\textrm{stuff}.$$

Where I do not know how to write "stuff" in general.

---

For visualization, here is the case for $k=2$:

$$\sum_{i_1,i_2}A_{i_1}A_{i_2}=
\sum_{i_1} A_{i_1} A_{i_1}
+\sum_{i_1<i_2}(A_{i_1}A_{i_2}+A_{i_2}A_{i_1})$$

and for $k=3$:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3}A_{i_1}A_{i_2}A_{i_3}&=
\sum_{i_1} A_{i_1} A_{i_1} A_{i_1}\\
&+\sum_{i_1<i_2}(A_{i_1}A_{i_1}A_{i_2}+A_{i_1}A_{i_2}A_{i_1}+A_{i_2}A_{i_1}A_{i_1}+A_{i_2}A_{i_2}A_{i_1}+A_{i_2}A_{i_1}A_{i_2}+A_{i_1}A_{i_2}A_{i_2})\\
&+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}(A_{i_1}A_{i_2}A_{i_3}+A_{i_1}A_{i_3}A_{i_2}+A_{i_2}A_{i_1}A_{i_3}+A_{i_2}A_{i_3}A_{i_1}+A_{i_3}A_{i_1}A_{i_2}+A_{i_3}A_{i_2}A_{i_1})
\end{align}$$

---

Clearly for the case with general $k$ we will need some permutation operator, i.e. for the sum $\sum_{i_1<..<i_q}$ of $k$ $A$'s (where $q<k$) we have to use all $q$ indices at least once and then re-use in all possible ways for the remaining $k-q$ matrices in the product.